# Field needs to be parsed in SQL that looks like xml

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

I have a field in a sql table that looks like xml. I need to parse it out to get the field. It looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Vendor>
  <Vendor_ID><![CDATA[2 RIVERS CONTRA]]></Vendor_ID>
  <Vendor_Name><![CDATA[2 RIVERS CONTRACTING & SERVICES, INC.]]></Vendor_Name>
  <Vendor_Contact><![CDATA[]]></Vendor_Contact>
  <Phone><![CDATA[0                    ]]></Phone>
  <Address><![CDATA[P.O. BOX 1512  ]]></Address>
  <City><![CDATA[ARLINGTON]]></City>
  <State><![CDATA[MA]]></State>
  <Country><![CDATA[]]></Country>
</Vendor>
```

I need to pull out such fields as CDATA[2 RIVERS CONTRA

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: question contains too little specific content.

Comment: sorry it did not take the code the first time. Thanks

Comment: Use the {} button to make more readable code... however the request still doesn't make sense to me. What exactly are you trying to pull out, and based on what criteria?

Comment: Also: although tag suggest this would be question wrt sql-server, it's better to explicitly explain it in question; as well as whether access should be via SQL extensions, or from some programming language (on client side)

Comment: Thanks for the help above. I am new to this site and learning the ropes.

Answer (score 1):

Not only does it looks like XML it **is** XML.

If the column in your table is an XML data type column you can get the value like this.

```
select XMLCol.value('(/Vendor/Vendor_ID)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Vendor_ID
from YourTable
```

If it is a varchar/nvarchar column you need to first cast to XML.

```
select cast(XMLCol as xml).value('(/Vendor/Vendor_ID)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Vendor_ID
from YourTable
```

Working sample:

```
declare @YourTable table (XMLCol varchar(max))

insert into @YourTable values
('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Vendor>
    <Vendor_ID><![CDATA[2 RIVERS CONTRA]]></Vendor_ID>
    <Vendor_Name><![CDATA[2 RIVERS CONTRACTING & SERVICES, INC.]]></Vendor_Name>
    <Vendor_Contact><![CDATA[]]></Vendor_Contact>
    <Phone><![CDATA[0                    ]]></Phone>
    <Address><![CDATA[P.O. BOX 1512  ]]></Address>
    <City><![CDATA[ARLINGTON]]></City>
    <State><![CDATA[MA]]></State>
    <Country><![CDATA[]]></Country>
  </Vendor>')

select cast(XMLCol as xml).value('(/Vendor/Vendor_ID)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Vendor_ID
from @YourTable
```

Result:

```
Vendor_ID
----------------
2 RIVERS CONTRA
```